# opencart create new module with order

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I am new to opencart and want to create new extension module. After order placed and payment process completed after that I need to call 3rd party API.

So, Is there any hooks (like WordPress or Prestashop) that I can apply and use into my module files?

I am currently using opencart version - 2.3.0.2

Answer (score 1):

OpenCart doesn't have any hooks, only events system, which is pretty weak. Instead it uses [VQMod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod). This is a pretty powerful tool for developers, who know some PHP. It works similar to WordPress hooks, but gives you unlimited options.

Hooks use certain points in the code or fire certain events, but with VQMod you can put your code literally anywhere. You only need to find the desired line and put your code before or after it, even replace it, if necessary.

If you're familiar with WP hooks and filters, I'm pretty sure you'll handle VQMod well.

Answer (score 1):

There are three following way :

1. **[Opencart Events](http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/10/24/opencart-2-x-x-event-system-tutorial/)**
2. **[Vqmod](http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/12/02/how-to-install-vqmod/)**
3. **[Ocmod](http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/12/02/how-to-install-vqmod/)**

**PS**: I prefer to use ocmod.